# HttpContext in .ashx show always the same value

Tags: httpcontext, jqgrid-asp.net

I have two JQGrids. I use onSelectRow and the value of my rowid i send to a .ashx Handler through the second JQGrid. Based on that value i populate the second JQGrid with the help of the .ashx

```
$("#FirstGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
onSelectRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
       var $gridSecond = $('#SecondGrid');
                $gridPng.jqGrid({
                    scroll: 5,
                    url: 'JQTestLoader.ashx?code=' + rowid,
                    datatype: "json",
```

In Handler i have:

```
 public class JQTestLoader : IHttpHandler
 {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
     string test = context.Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
```

The HttpContext shows the right rowid only the first time. If i click some other row than i still get the value of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to first call the GridUnload Method and than create the Grid again